# Vaadin 14 grid horizontal scrollbar auto-movement

Tags: sorting, grid, focus, scrollbar, vaadin

I have a grid with many columns that are sortable. If I mark one of them for sorting (by clicking on the header and simply enabling the sorting) and then move the scrollbar so that the sorting column disappears, and change the focus by clicking either outside of the grid or on the searchbar attached to the grid, and then I re-focus on the grid again, the horizontal scrollbar moves automatically to the column that I sort by, so the said column is centered. This is very annoying.

I am using Vaadin 14. Has anyone encountered such an issue and knows the workaround for it?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This is not because of the sorting per se, but because of cell focus. When you focus the Grid using the keyboard (i.e. tab/shift-tab), the keyboard focus needs to go on a particular cell (since the Grid itself is not focusable). The Grid remembers which cell was focused last, so when you move focus to the Grid it delegates that focus to the previously focused cell.

When you click a header cell to sort a column, that cell also gets keyboard focus (like any other cell), so re-focusing it with tab/shift-tab will move focus to it, which of course means scrolling it into view in case it's not already there.

Unfortunately there's currently no API for resetting focus e.g. to the first column, but it's doable with a bit of javascript: https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/1254#issuecomment-491172696

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this is only a partial solution - it works when I am within a grid focus. However, if I use a search bar, filter panel or other component that gains a focus that is not a part of grid, the scrollbar "jumps" again. Wonder if I can lock it somehow so it doesn't move on it's own